# store value in JSON on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am new in JSON, i am trying to save data using JSON. I have a list of element with some button when we click the button i want the corresponding value of button are save in JSON. I am also want to compare the title with already exists in JSON.

Demo  [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/LjgcK/4/)

Comment: Do you mean you want to compare the title of the currently clicked button with a previously saved one?

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with JSON, rather it's about arrays and [object initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers), which are also known as object literals.

Comment: where is the json part?

Comment: Yes i want to compare the title with already exist on json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `for` loop to check if the element with that title is already there:

```
function alreadyAdded(itemTitle) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
        if (objArray[i].title === itemTitle) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Also, you are not using a json object, just a JavaScript array.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LjgcK/5/)

Comment: what is objectArry here

Comment: @Subhash it is an array of objects. Look at demo.

Comment: thanks it work, now i want to retrive this JSON values in other page in the form of table, is this posiible

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to store values in an array, and during a button click you want to check if the item already exists in the array. If this is true, then you can use the following code -

```
var counter = 0;
var jsonObj = []; //declare object 

$('.imgbtn').click(function () {
    var title = $(this).parent().parent().find('span').html();
    var image = $(this).parent().parent().find('img').prop('src');
    var match = $.grep(jsonObj, function (e) { 
        return e.title == title; 
    });

    if (match.length > 0) {
        // This title already exists in the object.
        // Do whatever you want. I am simply returning.
        return;
    }

    counter++;
    $('#lblCart').html(counter);
    jsonObj.push({
        id: counter,
        title: title,
        image: image,
        description: 'Example'
    });
});
```

Notice that I have declared the array outside the callback function. This ensures that all the invocation of the callback operate on the same array object. Declaring it inside the callback was only making it available for a single callback invocation.

Also note that you are simply using an array to store plain JavaScript Objects.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LjgcK/7/).

Answer (score 0):

try this
http://jsfiddle.net/Z3v4g/

```
var counter = 0;
var jsonObj = []; //declare object

    $('.imgbtn').click(function () {

        var title = $(this).parent().parent().find('span').html();
        var image = $(this).parent().parent().find('img').prop('src');

        for( var i=0; i<jsonObj.length; i++){
           if( jsonObj[i].title == title ) return false;
        };

        counter++;
        $('#lblCart').html(counter);

        jsonObj.push({
           id: counter,
           title: title,
           image: image,
           description: 'Example'
           });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
var jsonObj = []; //declare object
```

This is not a JSON. This is an Array. JSON is just the notation of Javascript Object. To declare a object you should do:

```
var jsonObj = {};
```

or:

```
var jsonObj = new Object();
```

After this, you can approach what you asked doing this:

```
var counter = 0;
var jsonObj = new Object();

$('.imgbtn').click(function () {
   var title = $(this).parent().parent().find('span').html();
   var image = $(this).parent().parent().find('img').prop('src');    
   if (!(title in jsonObj)) { // if item is not in the object, (title in jsonObj) returns true of false
       jsonObj[title] = { // When you have hundreds of items, this approach is way faster then using FOR loop, and if you need to alter the item or get one value, you can just call it by name: jsonObj['ABC'].image will return the path of the image
           id: counter,
           image: image,
           description: 'Example'
       }
       counter++;
       $('#lblCart').html(counter);
   } else {
       // Do what you want if the item is already in the list
       alert('Item already in the list');
       console.log(jsonObj[title]);
   }
});
```

DON'T use FOR loops to do what you wan't, it will just slow down your application if the counter gets high.