# Arrange JSON data in table format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

In previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584727/store-value-in-json-on-button-click) my problem is resolved but now after that i am trying JSON data store in cookies and then retrieve that other variable and arrange it in table format, but i'm confuse that how i arrange it.

Demo [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/LjgcK/16/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you are trying to convert it json and again parsing, but this is the other way to directly get from the array and populate it to table.

```
$('#btnCart').click(function () {
    //var value = JSON.stringify(objArray);
    var table = "<table><tr><td>Id</td><td>Title</td><td></tr>"; 
     $.each(objArray, function (k, v) {
       table=table+"<tr><td>"+objArray[k].id +"</td><td>"+objArray[k].title +"</td></tr>";
     });
 table=table+"</table>";
 $('#divGrid').empty();
 $('#divGrid').append(table);
});
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LjgcK/19/)

Answer (score 0):

convert it according to your requirement

js:

```
function getNews(){
   $.getJSON("services/news_service.php?action=getNews", function(json){

   $.each(json.news, function(){
        var news = '<tr>'+'<td width="52"><span class="news_item_div"> <img src="'+imagePath+this['news_icon']+'" alt="" name="news_icon" width="51" height="51" class="news_icon" id="news_icon" /></span></td>'+
    '<td width="128">' +this['news_headline']+ '</td>'+
  '</tr>';
      $('#news table').append(news);
                   });
   });


 }
```

html:

```
<div id="news">
        <table width="200" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget to use templating: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. error in closing span 


<span id='lblCart'></span>

2. Not properly assigned the values

table=table+"<tr><td>"+v.id +"</td><td>"+v.title +"</td></tr>";
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LjgcK/21/)**